Need of Synchronization in threads in JAVA
While using Synchronization my threads are working one after the other , the same happens when i have only one thread which executes the instructions one after the other so what's the use of creating multiple threads.


class Myclass1 extends Thread
{
        public void run()
        {
         System.out.println("Running in class 1");
        }

}

class Myclass2 extends Thread
{
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("Running in class 2");
        }
}

class Driver
{
     synchronized public static void main(String[]args)
      {
        Myclass1 obj1=new Myclass1();
        Myclass2 obj2=new Myclass2();
        obj1.start();
        obj2.start();
        System.out.println("Hello");
      }
}



In this specific case, there's no benefit. But what if the two threads were each doing an expensive calculation, or maybe each downloading a big file? It would be better to do them both at the same time, rather than doing one, then doing the other. That's what threads do.

Re, "While using Synchronization..." Just to be clear, there is no synchronization in your code.* Your main routine synchronizes on the Driver.class object, but since no other thread in the program ever synchronizes on that same object, that's effectively the same as no synchronization at all. [*There is synchronization in the println method that is called by your code, which is why, even though you may see the three lines printed in different orders, you will never see output from two or more threads mixed into a single line.]

Steven C said, in a nutshell, that threads can be used to achieve parallel computations. That's true, but it's not the only thing that threads are good for. In fact, threads were in wide-spread use long before parallel computation was possible outside of cutting-edge computer engineering laboratories.
Threads are a model of concurrent computing, which is a broader category. All parallel algorithms are concurrent algorithms, but not all concurrent algorithms exploit parallelism. Simply put, "concurrency" means that the program has two or more activities that run, mostly independently of each other, at the same time.
A classic example is a network server that is able to serve several different clients at the same time. Whatever it's doing for any one client may be completely unrelated to what it's doing for any other client. If the server creates one thread for each active client, then the state of the work that any thread is doing for its client is implicit in the context registers and the call stack of the thread—That is to say, the program counter and the currently nested function calls and the local variables of those functions contain all of the information about what the thread is doing for the client.
That makes reading the code easy* because the code looks just like the code of a single-threaded server that can only handle one client at a time would look. It looks just like the single-threaded code that we all learned to write when we were beginners. One alternative to using a thread-per-client is to have a single thread call something like Linux's select to await the next message from any client, and then it has to look up an object that explicitly encodes the state of that client, and call some routine that continues the work from that point onward. Some servers are built that way, and for good reasons, but their code can be significantly more complicated than the thread-per-client model.
Note that, in the case of our thread-per-client server, if there are multiple CPUs available, the program will automatically exploit them, and handle simultaneous client requests in truly parallel fashion, but even with just a single CPU, the model still works, and the benefits of multi-threading still are worth while.

* Reading multithreaded code may be easy, but writing correct multithreaded code is a whole 'nother story. Even so, code that gets written one time may be read many times, so even just making it easier to read usually is a win.

Your example is too simple to demonstrate the usefulness of threads.
Basically you are printing 3 messages: two in the child threads and the third one after the threads have been started.  When I run the code, I get a variety of message orders.  However, this is what I would expect to happen since the code doesn't constrain the ordering of the messages in any way.  (Indeed all 6 permutations are possible.)

Threads are useful when your program needs to do multiple non-trivial computations.  For example, suppose that you are trying to find the one millionth digit of the square root of N, for N in the range 1 to 20.  And suppose that you already have a method that computes this for one value of N:
public static int computeDigit(int n) {
    // Compute the 1,000,000th digit of squareroot(n)
    return ...
}

And suppose that it takes up to 10 seconds to compute this (I'm guessing ...)
In a single threaded application, you could complete the task like this:
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    int answer = computeDigit(i);
    System.out.println("Answer for " + i + " is " + answer);
}

This would compute and print the answers one at a time, and would take up to 20 * 10 == 200 seconds.
In a multi-threaded application, you could complete the task like this:
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    new Thread(n -> { int answer = computeDigit(n);
                      System.out.println("Answer for " + n +
                                         " is " + answer);
                    }
              ).start();
}

(I am using a Java lambda there ... look it up.)
This would produce the same output, but probably in a different order. The time taken would depend on the number of physical cores available to the application.

If there were 2 cores, two threads could run simultaneously, and the overall time would be halved.
If there 4 cores, the time would be divided by 4.
If there were 20 (or 40 or 80) cores, the time would be roughly 10 seconds.

In summary, multiple threads allow you to do computations on multiple cores simultaneously.  In some cases this can give you a significant speedup (or a significant increase in throughput).

The multithreading is still working.

The synchronized keyword in the code you have shared, is not getting used essentially. The driver method main is always run by the main thread. Since your code does not access the main method from different threads, the synchronized keyword is redundant there. The keyword is used to put a lock on a method/block so that a new method can't access it at the same time.
When you run the above program multiple times, you may be able to notice that the print statements are not in fixed order. For instance, I was able to get this result from your code:
Out-of-order print statements due to multithreading.


Make a tortoise of your hare
The other Answers are good. But here is the simplest explanation: Your code makes for a poor example because it runs too fast.

Your main thread does not wait for the other threads to work. So you might see "Hello" without seeing any output from the others. Or you might see either Myclass1 or Myclass2 do their thing in any order.
Your simple one line of code calling println is not a good demo for seeing parallel threads at work. Slow them down, perhaps by adding some sleep and some more calls to println.

System.out is not chronological
Output to System.out does not necessarily appear in chronological order when called across threads. You must add timestamps, and study them, to verify what happened in what order.
Revised code
In our revised version of your code we:

Added calls to sleep and to println in Myclass1 or Myclass2.
Added a sleep to the main method to give the threads some time to work.
Added calls to Instant.now everywhere to verify actual event order.

public class ExSimple
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "`main` start at: " + Instant.now( ) );

        Myclass1 obj1 = new Myclass1( );
        Myclass2 obj2 = new Myclass2( );
        obj1.start( );
        obj2.start( );

        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 20 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
        System.out.println( "`main` done at: " + Instant.now( ) );
    }
}

class Myclass1 extends Thread
{
    public void run ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "Start class 1. On thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread( ).threadId( ) + Instant.now( ) );
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 4 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
        System.out.println( "Middle class 1. " + Instant.now( ) );
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 7 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
        System.out.println( "End class 1. " + Instant.now( ) );
    }
}

class Myclass2 extends Thread
{
    public void run ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "Start class 2. On thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread( ).threadId( ) + Instant.now( ) );
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 2 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
        System.out.println( "Middle class 2. " + Instant.now( ) );
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 13 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
        System.out.println( "End class 2. " + Instant.now( ) );
    }
}

Here is some example output. The lines appear in the order we would expect given our staggered sleep durations.
Start class 1. On thread ID: 212024-07-30T04:59:58.860181Z
Start class 2. On thread ID: 222024-07-30T04:59:58.860307Z
Middle class 2. 2024-07-30T05:00:00.873229Z
Middle class 1. 2024-07-30T05:00:02.873274Z
End class 1. 2024-07-30T05:00:09.886505Z
End class 2. 2024-07-30T05:00:13.880383Z
`main` done at: 2024-07-30T05:00:18.867635Z

Drop synchronized
Your synchronized on the main method is unnecessary, irrelevant, and confusing. Using synchronized does not affect your particular example.
Executors framework
By the way, do not extend Thread to use it as a Runnable. Making Thread implement Runnable was a flawed design choice made in haste when Java was rushed to market during the heady days of the World Wide Web invention.
Also, Java 5 brought the Executors framework to relieve us Java programmers of the error-prone chore of juggling threads. We rarely need to address the Thread class directly.
Instead, write your tasks in a class (or lambda) that implements either Runnable or Callable. Then instantiate a ExecutorService via the Executors utility class. And submit instances of your task class to that executor service.
For most purposes, generally best to use virtual threads with some caveats.
